# Angular material select element not aligned with other form controls

Tags: angular-material

While designing a form using Angular Material I noticed that the `<md-select>` directive is not aligned with the other input controls. See below:

[image]

I literally copied the code from the [example](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.input) on the Angular Material page, and added the `<md-select>`. Here is my code:

```
<div layout="column" layout-padding>
<md-content>
    <form>
        <div layout layout-sm="column">
            <md-select placeholder="Title" ng-model="vm.title">
                <md-option value="Mr">Mr.</md-option>
                <md-option value="Mrs">Mrs.</md-option>
                <md-option value="Ms">Ms.</md-option>
            </md-select>
            <md-input-container flex>
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input ng-model="vm.lastName">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container flex>
                <label>First name</label>
                <input ng-model="vm.firstName">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <md-input-container flex>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input ng-model="vm.address">
        </md-input-container>
    </form>
</md-content>
```

I tried adding an `<md-input-container>` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I discovered this [post](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1638) on GitHub straight after posting: apparently it has already been fixed in the one of the latest commits to master.